# How to extract the year from a file path in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have file paths like these from which i want to extract the year :

```
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\ABC\V.1\SubFolder\1950\file.ext
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\BCD\V.1\SubFolder1\1987\file1.ext
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\ABC\V.1\SubFolder\1987_dup\file1.ext
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\CDA\V.1\SubFolder1\1950\file.ext
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\ABC\V.1\SubFolder\1997\file1.ext
\\Main\Folder\Folder1\Folder2\123456\XYZ\V.1\SubFolder3\1997_dup\file1.ext
...
```

Observe that the year i want to extract are the 1st 4 characters after 10 "\"'s in the path.
Any Help is appreciated, thankYou!

Comment: thanks for the input @pnuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily find N-th character by substituting it to something else using optional parameter of SUBSTITUTE function - it replaces the N-th occurrence of the character. So just replace it with something that can not be in the filepath and the use it to find the year.

```
=MID(A1;FIND("@";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"\";"@";10))+1;4)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution and creative function combination.

Comment: thank you rwking, I first found out about this when my wife asked my to find a function that would separate street name and street number. when you have streets with various number of words and even with numbers inside like "street of 28th October" then you start running out of options :-)

Comment: @Pavel_V Good technique. The only rationale I can think of for why OP did not pick your solution is that perhaps he was not familiar with the semicolons in his neck of the woods... and as a result could not confirm your formula.

Comment: @Pavel_V : This works Great too, a smart and better solution, thank you very much. took a little time for me to figure out !!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an excel formula: I think I have 10 "\" in there for you. Try this:

```
=MID(D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,FIND("\",D7,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,4)
```

Comment: I assumed the info was in cell D7 for this formula. Change as needed.

Comment: Works perfect! Thankyou very much.